# How to get ClassLoader from type variable (for parceling a class using generics)

Tags: java, android, generics, parcelable

I have a parcelable class with a generic type object. Usually I would read out that object like this:

```
in.readParcelable(MyParcelableClass.class.getClassLoader())
```

Apparently I can't do that with a generic type variable.. see code below. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

```
public class ParcelableOverlayItem<T extends Parcelable> extends OverlayItem implements Parcelable {

  private T parcelableTypeObject;

  protected ParcelableOverlayItem(Parcel in) {
    this(in.readParcelable(T.class.getClassLoader())); // this is not working: "Cannot select from a type variable"
  }

  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(parcelableTypeObject, flags);
  }

  public ParcelableOverlayItem(T parcelableTypeObject) {
    super();
    this.parcelableTypeObject = parcelableTypeObject;
  }

  public T getParcelableTypeObject() {
    return parcelableTypeObject;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Should be ParcelableOverlayItem<T extends Parcelable>

Comment: I actually already corrected that, thanks anyway appreciate it!

Comment: A workaround is to receive the type of `T` in the constructor of `ParcelableOverlayItem` and storing it in the Parcel before `T`. Then when reading you can do `this(in.readParcelable(typeOfT.class.getClassLoader()));`. [Check the source code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28069422/3715151).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `ClassLoader` from generic type `T` like this

```
this(in.readParcelable(parcelableTypeObject.getClass().getClassLoader()));
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, IDEA tells me `Cannot reference 'ParcelableOverlayItem.parcelableTypeObject' before supertype constructor has been called`

Comment: @Blacklight is your `OverlayItem` class has  has parameterized constructor? if yes, you need to call super class Constrcutor in ParcelableOverlayItem like `super(parameter)`...

Comment: Yes it does and I am calling super with parameters, I just simplified my example, it wouldn't make a difference. This is the super-class: http://goo.gl/lBJwi9